# Python 3 - using tuples in str.format()

Tags: python, string, tuples, string-formatting

I'm trying to use the `str.format()` method, and having some difficulties when my values are stored within a tuple. For example, if I do:

```
s = "x{}y{}z{}"
s.format(1,2,3)
```

Then I get `'x1y2z3'` - no problem.
However, when I try:

```
s = "x{}y{}z{}"
tup = (1,2,3)
s.format(tup)
```

I get

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range.
```

So how can I 'convert' the tuple into separate variables? or any other workaround ideas?

Comment: You are actually passing a single argument that is a `tuple`.

Comment: def fun(*args):    print('My args: {!a}'.format(args))

I just don't know yet what 'a' means, but it seems to be a 'conversion specifier'. I've also seen the use of 'r'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Pass in the tuple using [`*arg` variable arguments call syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters):

```
s = "x{}y{}z{}"
tup = (1,2,3)
s.format(*tup)
```

The `*` before `tup` tells Python to unpack the tuple into separate arguments, as if you called `s.format(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2])` instead.

Or you can index the first positional argument:

```
s = "x{0[0]}y{0[1]}z{0[2]}"
tup = (1,2,3)
s.format(tup)
```

Demo:

```
>>> tup = (1,2,3)
>>> s = "x{}y{}z{}"
>>> s.format(*tup)
'x1y2z3'
>>> s = "x{0[0]}y{0[1]}z{0[2]}"
>>> s.format(tup)
'x1y2z3'
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but can you explain more what's actually going on with the *? or refer me to the right place in the documentation?

Comment: @soungalo: see [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901)

Comment: This really helpful if used inside map() and you don't want to define lambda or custom function to use `*` to unpack the tuple! This is the only solution (that I could find) that talks about indexing in format to unpack tuple. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

You can unpack the contants of the tuple.

`s=s.format(*t)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything not already covered in an existing answer.

Comment: @Kevin - So downvote it. Don't flag it.

Comment: shorter is better