# How to use a tuple with string.format with out splitting beforehand

Tags: python

I've this working code:

```
', '.join('%s=%r' % item for item in list)
```

where `list` is list of tuples `('key', 'value')`.

I want to refactore the code to use the new style string.format. I've tried it this way:

```
', '.join(['{!s}={!r}'.format(item) for item in list])
```

This results in an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Are there any better solutions than:

```
arguments = []
for key, value in list:
    arguments.append('{!s}={!r}'.format(key, value))

', '.join(arguments)
```

Context:

```
def __repr__(self):
    """
    This method returns a string representation of the object such that eval() can recreate the object.
    The class attributes will be ordered
    e.g. Class(attribute1='String', attribute2=3)
    """
    list =[]
    for item in vars(self).items():
        list.append(item)
    list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])

    arguments = []
    for key, value in list:
        arguments.append('{!s}={!r}'.format(key, value))

    return '{!s}({!s})'.format(
        type(self).__name__,
        ', '.join(arguments)
    )
```

Comment: Unpack: `'{!s}={!r}'.format(*item)`

Comment: `', '.join(['{!s}={!r}'.format(*item) for item in list])` try unpacking the item with the `*` operator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758341/python-3-using-tuples-in-str-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack your tuple.

```
>>> t = ('a', 'b')
>>> '{!s}={!r}'.format(*t)
"a='b'"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `', '.join(['{!s}={!r}'.format(item[0], item[1]) for item in list])` ?